# How to use KNeighborsClassifier in BaggingClassifier & How to solve "KNN doesn't support sample weights issue"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn, voting, ensemble-learning

I am new to Sklearn, and I am trying to combine KNN, Decision Tree,  SVM, and Gaussian NB for BaggingClassifier.

Part of my code looks like this:

```
best_KNN = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, p=1)
best_KNN.fit(X_train, y_train)

majority_voting = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('KNN', best_KNN), ('DT', best_DT), ('SVM', best_SVM), ('gaussian', gaussian_NB)], voting='hard')
majority_voting.fit(X_train, y_train)

bagging = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=majority_voting)
bagging.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

But this causes an error saying:

> TypeError: Underlying estimator KNeighborsClassifier does not support sample weights.

The "bagging" part worked fine if I remove KNN.
Does anyone have any idea to solve this issue? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `BaggingClassifier` you can only use base estimators that support sample weights because it relies on [score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.score) method, which takes in `sample_weight`param.

You can list all the available classifiers like:

```
import inspect 
from sklearn.utils.testing import all_estimators 
for name, clf in all_estimators(type_filter='classifier'): 
    if 'sample_weight' in inspect.getargspec(clf.fit)[0]: 
        print(name)
```